# When a php file code is changed during a session using fwrite, will the new php file always be considered in successive sessions?

Tags: php, session, dynamic

Is there a complete guarantee of this or even if the session that modifies the file is over there may be some kind of delay in the following sessions?

Which server variables could affect this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is guaranteed if you are using php via a cgi interface, but probably not if used as a module inside an http server. I am unsure about a fastcgi environment...

Apart from that it is very risky and usually not considered good style or architecture to have a process modify its own code. That can open *huge* security issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer arkascha. About the security issues, if the process that modifies the code can only be executed from a secured administrator console is it still considered a bad architecture?

Comment: There are two aspects to be considered: 1. how secure is that "secured administrator console" and 2. how do you want to realize such a limitation? Typically your approach means the php file has to be writable by the http server process. In that case it is _not_ limited to that console, whatever that is.

Comment: Right now, the console and the files that are dynamically modified are inside a .htpasswd protected folder. Anyways, those files are turned to non-writable right after using the console through sftp connection (and made writable through the same sftp connection before using the console). Is that still insecure?

Comment: `.htaccess` style files cause many problems, they are notoriously error prone. But anyways, just the file alone says nothing, question is what kind of protection is implemented in it. The part about file permission control via the ssh server sounds OK. Sorry, I expected the "secured administrator console" to be a web access too. Though I don't see how that can actually work: if that ssh account is a separate one from the http server process, then why do the permissions have to be altered at all? That makes no sense... But anyways, you know what you are doing, I just wanted to mention security.

Comment: Well... the console is in fact a web based one. It's used to perform some quick code changes without having to upload any files and to show extensive information about the changes performed. Then the ssh is used to change those files permissions just as a security layer.